# string replacement with sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

```
        [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMMOVE]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMMOVE

            [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMEQBC

            [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQCM]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMEQCM

            [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMLMOV]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMLMOV
sed -i 's/[Aa0-Zz9]*.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC/DEF.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC/g' param_file.parm
```

Folder names patterns are 
Data_Foundation 
DataFoundation 
Data_Foundation12 
DataFoundation12

string pattern 
[FOLDERNMAE.WF:$wf_name]
i have to repalce foldername (datafoundatio for example) with EFG (which is a variable)
    sed -i 's/[A-Za-z0-9]*.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC/EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC/g' test

when i use above sed command, i am getting below output

[Data_EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC]

Actual output is [EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC]

Comment: `[Aa0-Zz9]` contains invalid character ranges.  You probably need `[A-Za-z0-9]` or `[[:alnum:]]`.

Comment: Expected output is not clear As per my understanding below command will work 
 sed "s/Data_Foundation/ABCDEF/g" filename

Comment: Folder names patterns are 
Data_Foundation 
DataFoundation 
Data_Foundation12 
DataFoundation12

string pattern 
[FOLDERNMAE.WF:$wf_name]

i have to repalce foldername (datafoundatio for example) with EFG (which is a variable)
sed -i 's/[A-Za-z0-9]*.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC/EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC/g' test

when i use above sed command, i am getting below output

[Data_EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC]

Actual output is [EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat test.txt
 [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMMOVE]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMMOVE

            [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMEQBC

            [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQCM]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMEQCM

            [Data_Foundation.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMLMOV]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMLMOV
$
$ echo ${VAR}
EFG
$
$ sed "s/.*\(\.*WF.*$\)/\[$VAR.\1/" test.txt
[EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMMOVE]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMMOVE

[EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQBC]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMEQBC

[EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMEQCM]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMEQCM

[EFG.WF:wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMLMOV]
    $Param_Object_Name=RKEMLMOV
```

Comment: It worked as expected. Could you please help me understand the above command as I have to check the patteren starting with "[" Also, I am trying to replace wrokflow(wf_STG_SIM_RKEM_RKEMMOVE) as variable but i am getting some error when replaced this value as $WRKFL

Comment: can you edit your question with clear input file and the variable value and the expected output.